# Serverless lambda function throwing error when trying to insert data into dynamoDB Table

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to test CRUD functionality on a aws lambda function using the Serverless Framework.

Here is the command I am running:

```
sudo serverless invoke local -f createArticle -p articles/event.json
```

When I try to create a record an error is thrown. Here is the error in the console:

```
Syntax Error -------------------------------------------

 Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

 For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
Get Support --------------------------------------------
 Docs:          docs.serverless.com
 Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
 Forums:        forum.serverless.com
 Chat:          gitter.im/serverless/serverless

Your Environment Information -----------------------------
 OS:                 darwin
 Node Version:       6.10.3
 Serverless Version: 1.13.1
```

Now I have linted my javascript and validated my event.json file.

Here is my javascript:

```js
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const uuid = require('uuid');

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  if (data.text && typeof data.text !== 'string') {
    console.log('Validation Failed');
    callback(new Error('Body did not contain a text property.'));
    return;
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: 'BlogTable',
    Item: {
      article_id: "1",
      text: data.text
    }
  };

  const putCallback = (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      callback(new Error('Could not save record.'));
      return;
    }
    //console.log(result);
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.Item)
    };
    callback(null, response);
  }
  dynamo.put(params, putCallback);
};
```

Here is my `event.json` file:

```
{"text":"Hello World"}
```

Why is the error getting thrown? And how do I set that environmental variable I tried in my `serverless.yml` file but I did not get any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "Lambda proxy" integration, you need to use a specific format for `http://` events that directly invoke your Lambda functions (e.g. if you use `serverless invoke` from the CLI, and not the AWS API Gateway Management Console, where you can invoke the Lambda function through your API using the "Test" button).

With a Lambda proxy, in this example, you need to create a json file with a "body" property and stringify the value, like this:

```
{
  "body": "{\"text\":\"hello\"}"
}
```

The reason is: "With the Lambda proxy integration, API Gateway maps the entire client request to the input event parameter of the back-end Lambda function"
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format

Comment: Why does the `body` have to have a `text` property? Is there a way I can override this?

Answer (score 0):

In my event.json files I had to put my json like this:

```
{"body": "{\"text\": \"Hello World\"}"
```